# Make questions with bad reputation not indexed in Google

Tags: feature-request, questions, google, noindex

When I search for particular programming problems on Google, I am always excited (and also always hoping) to see SO results on page one so I can just click them and get my answers, however sometimes (if not often) those links are links to questions with a lot of down vote or sadly even without answers. Take this example, result nr. 5

http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=formsauthentication+failed

My question (to SO team): Is it a good idea to flag questions with bad reputation as being "no-index"? so that those SO results on Google are only the best ones?

I know I can search directly within SO website but one of the advantages searching on Google is that I have more options.

Answer (score 6):

I've got mixed feelings about this.  I know it can be disappointing to click on a promising link only to find a question with no answer.  However, [some questions with low votes *have* good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/95/reversal).  Also, there are a lot of [unanswered questions that I'd like to see get *more* exposure](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed), not less.  I don't know if it's a good idea to remove any open questions from search results.  The people who find them from Google might be the ones who end up answering.

Comment: But sadly, most of those wonderful answers are now defunct. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88709/the-lost-worlds-of-the-reversal-badge

Comment: @Wether: Right, but I was only using those as an example that bad questions do get good answers.  The deleted ones won't show up in a Google search anyway.

Comment: closed questions, which cannot get new answers, which have no answer which is highly voted on, are pretty much dead stubs of the internet. They are also a waste of a Google user's time. E.G. I googled how to play back Skype's dat voicemail format. SO came up twice in results, I trust SO, so I read them, even though it's definitely not an SO question. Guess what. Closed, no actionable information.

Comment: @dlamblin This feature request isn't about closed questions, it's about questions with low score.

Comment: @BilltheLizard if that's how you read it; of all the questions with bad reputation, some of them are also closed questions.